# Issues with Concurrent Mode failure

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory, jvm-arguments

```
Here are the gc log details

2013-10-30T17:37:27.285+0100: 1250455.686: [GC 1250455.686: [ParNew
        Desired survivor size 51445760 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 4)
        - age   1:   91404824 bytes,   91404824 total
        : 881572K->89325K(904384K), 0.0359086 secs] 2755473K->2052121K(2914176K)  icms_dc=100 , 0.0362248 secs] [Times: user=0.12 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs] 

2013-10-30T17:37:27.714+0100: 1250456.115: [GC 1250456.116: [ParNew: 877881K->877881K(904384K), 0.0000232 secs]1250456.116: [CMS2013-10-30T17:37:27.937+0100: 1250456.338: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 2.608/3.118 secs] [Times: user=8.55 sys=0.14, real=3.12 secs] 
         **(concurrent mode failure):** 1962796K->1016548K(2009792K), 3.9820087 secs] 2840677K->1016548K(2914176K), [CMS Perm : 126257K->126176K(228356K)] icms_dc=100 , 3.9823002 secs] [Times: user=3.76 sys=0.01, real=3.98 secs] 

2013-10-30T17:37:31.717+0100: 1250460.122: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 1016548K(2009792K)] 1038948K(2914176K), 0.0044446 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

I did not see any FULL GC's happening.

The problem is ParNew that increases and consume the whole CPU usage. Is there anything you could predict with this?

JVM parameters are these

```
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xmx2944m
```

-Xms2944m

Comment: Why are you using Incremental mode? For modern machines, this is rarely a good choice, due to the safepointing behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent mode failure means what at the moment of young collection, free space in old collection wasn't enough to accommodate estimated amount of object to be promoted.

Old space collection was already scheduled, so instead of doing Full GC, JVM has waited for Old space GC to complete (and it has freed enough space to finish young GC).

In CMS mode
FullGC - is implemented as stop-the-world Mark Sweep Compact which clears both young and old
Old GC - is Concurrent Mark Sweep algorithm working in the background which clears only old space

Concurrent mode failure may or may not trigger Full GC (in your case completeting Old GC was enough)

Root cause of your problem is improperly configured GC options. I would suggest you too remove (because they are interfering with `-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode`)

```
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

You can find more information about tuning CMS in [my blog](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/07/gc-check-list-for-data-grid-nodes.html).

Comment: I can also see that there is some problem with the threshold since the calculated one is 1 and max is 4 and moreover the Desired survivor size 51445760 bytes is also less than 91404824 bytes. So would you suggest anything to tune this.

Comment: It is possible what age size is calculate wrong, there is open bug in JVM https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027363